# Validating against a variable number of columns in Spark

Tags: validation, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

​I have a bunch of codes indicating the stages a person has been in my data displayed horizontally as shown below.

```
Name code1 code2 code3 code4
A 2 3. 4 Null
B 2 5 4 7
C 1 3 4 5
D 0 9 Null Null
```

I have another file which has all the valid codes.

```
ID Value
1  3
2  4
3  5
4  6
5  7
```

What I would like to do is validate all the columns cell by cell against this lookup and indicate `0` if they are valid and `null` if they are not valid.

I'm using Apache Spark 1.5.2 and I would like to do this the efficient way. I've tried bunch of combinations and only thing close to what I want I've come is using `concat` on the cells and then explode it as normalized table and then perform lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply with a single pass through the data, without any joins or `explode` by code-generating a validation expression:

```scala
// Simulate the data
case class Record(Name: String, code1: Option[Int], code2: Option[Int])
val dfData = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Record("A", Some(3), Some(4)), 
  Record("B", Some(3), None)
)).toDF.registerTempTable("my_data")

// Simulate the lookup table
val dfLookup = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,3), (2,4))).toDF("ID", "Value")

// Build a validation expression
val validationExpression = dfLookup.collect.map{ row => 
  s"code${row.getInt(0)} = ${row.getInt(1)}"
}.mkString(" and ")

// Add an is_valid column to the data
sql(s"select *, nvl($validationExpression, false) as is_valid from my_data").show
```

This produces:

```scala
defined class Record
dfData: Unit = ()
dfLookup: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, Value: int]
validationExpression: String = code1 = 3 and code2 = 4

+----+-----+-----+--------+
|Name|code1|code2|is_valid|
+----+-----+-----+--------+
|   A|    3|    4|    true|
|   B|    3| null|   false|
+----+-----+-----+--------+
```